# Парсер номера телефона с авито

Tags: python, парсер, requests, base64, обработка-изображений

На днях писал парсер авито (номер телефона считывать) и столкнулся с проблемой: номер телефона на сайте в виде картинки, а картинку скачать не получается. Написал такой код для скачивания картинки по ее url, но почему-то выдает ошибку, хотя другие картинки получается скачать

```py
import requests

p = requests.get('data:image/png;base64,<img_base64_str>')

out = open('img.jpg', 'wb')

out.write(p.content)

out.close()
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Вы получаете в `response` от сайта данные примерно такого вида:

```
{
    'anonymImage64': 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAT0AAAAyCAYAAAAuugz8AAAQtklEQVR4nOxdCZAXxdX/7cqyCAoeiOgHiFz6oRwin/IZSQAh0TIaTNTERK0QjTGJMWqi0UihZbziEY1RJCgemHhFI/HEI+CFgqKirPHgCCKinIHlPnb/qUm9SXX9eDPTPTP/3an9969qqnZq+3W/6X/36/dev9ddDQ8PD48Kghd6Hh4eFQUv9Dw8PCoKXuh5eHhUFLzQ8/DwqCh4oefh4VFR8ELPw8OjouCFnoeHR0XBCz0PD4+Kghd6Hh4eFQUv9Dw8PCoKrRzK9gcwDEAvALsD2ATgCwBvAHgRwPoy8skI2j8awCEAOorw/hzAbABTAWxIUWc7AHul5GcbgM8cyhepLwPsCuAY4aszgBoAKwHMBfC847cx9jB+q6B/t8u3BnU/Lt+eBb0BjAJwoPTlOgBLAbwC4GUApYz1p8VBwlfAXwcAa6QfpwOYWaY2g9/xEkOZuQnAsjK15YK8+BoIYLj0aXsAmwEslt/5VRlbuSD44d6UwRP1BD/olQDa5NVoBP4HwJ0iZKJ4CQb9jTIBXPDLhG+Me+ZbtlGkvoQsGHeI4IniJxhID4gwdEE7GdwbY+peC+BqAK1T8N4TwDMJfbkQwMkp6s6CgwG8lMDXB7LI5I27qJ2Dy9BGGmTla7jFvFkC4DxHRU7FZQAaHSb/HABdszYagaGifdjy8imA/3eo/09lFnpF6kuIprnKgZ/lAA61rHsfAHUOdb8FYG8H3kfI4mZbfyDYq1L2kwtOEO3Dlq/rc2z7JKX+Igi9rHyNc5w3r8pingq/iJCmtwA4H8ClstIyQ3WizueJL0UMpsBMuAbAhaJVLKD/rxdaG7hMUlehV6S+hKycG6itYEGZKLxeDOARAFuVMkmCuC2A94gu+O0eku8cJ2btdirzGoBaC94HKNpjYC7fBuAiGQ9vKf19dU59F4UvKxZIsPDeLOPzWgDvK3xdkEPbXQCsLqDQy8rXrxTaeWLJBVrdWABPAmhQFlFnS6mnMuBvijBDDpMJbJa9xbXBGHQUf51Z/2cAjlLK7gTg5zShlgLYM6GNNjRg35SJb/v8KKbuIvVlgG4A/kVt3Ct+F8YBAP5BZack1H8LlZ8NoLtSrh+Aj6nsbxPqbqUIjkCL21kpe4oi2Icn1J8WbUXAmW1dL75Rxtk0HhrEV5UWgQb7QsRi3JxCLytfA2lONsiCrG2+DlAUHudF7maq4O6E8geTJrYti4pJuI54WSaCJA6nEs3EhPKDqfxFOfGOgvUlRIMz+bktoXxnZbXuFVG2Fw3UxQmbQ11lUQrLBxrcvjHlzyY+Hk0wW79BWsDrCd+aFmMVQRyHMVT+yQxtXxAhWJpb6GXl63GiuTihfG/yTa8DsIsLw/NIwto4sf9ITJ7q0mAE2iq+m69b0j5KgiPOLDuT2hiRA+8hitKXEM3NNKHfsXT8jrMcgCzgbTYR2OdzbUzZD4xywQDvZFH/JKp/mAWNC2rIElllOdn+Rnz1S9F2f1ogvyiI0MvK1z60WP3TcpxOoHa+actwFZmHH1rS8eC9wrbBGBxNdb7hQHsk0cb5Tm41yjXm6EcrUl8GuIHqHWlJ15voHlDKVMtmR1hmmbgbklBNpuHCiHL/Rzz82ZL3/kQ33pLOFsdQ/b+3pBuR8TeulbAfU1u8tQBCLw++2FK7yrLt7xHdOK2QZh/X0mDdZtngOnrPQ3Dw7utfHWhnUrzbsTFlTZ/KQgmlyANF6ssAo42/PxKfiw0CbXUQgP1E+z5FKTOYTNmpslonoVE2cULsL20xOMTD1iR8T4RqiG/lvJOblq+XAdQb7yc6tnuNITxWAjjDkb5cyIOvN8U3P0n+nm5JxzGf7bRCmtDbLI7uED0sd9X60PtSC5ok7EPv7zjQBhrWJ8b7oRGDvUq0gRBvO/IYhyL1ZRfyhbosIJC+XxwTTDyE3l0CcNnXdmQZ6+8kmmteMPkKtItZlnTbZZMnxP9KILcNRsruZYizChKEnBdfH8mG2JmyuWe7OPPvukQrFJWG9nfj72Bl/05CY9WKRH8xmcdEtKf31Y705kraQYKbGT1p59IciNXiBztCtA/XAF0UqC8Po/e8swLYZJnrQMtmf/+E+teLnyfP+tMgWDD7Gu+LacyVg69AMN5jLOD3AnjMoc1yobn5aiXmrYnntIJRQu9GWbVC3BTjaK0SX5H5g81wWPHisJHetdCEOLDQ1HYG2ZSaLf6j+0TIfijf85Y4rOeLs912R7UofdmX3t83/m4jwvguSd+aJWbaVdIXNtif3qN8cxo+pfce9F4jmmoIF4FnU39adCITyuWbkZKvCcbiHQjZcx3bLBeak69Ajv2B5tUTojE6gXfs1klWQV+ZJIFk/5poMiXaqUkKKbHFtVS3i3+gtZJedbxFG4/Re9Sz1mFXtQh9eSdt1oRm9g/FBIn71qkxYSohOCDZJR2ohmjr6P/70v+fd/z244j+Bkf6KPAmibbBEwcOXUkKyzjdKNug7EQ310ZGc/HVSqI5OEVtseIas8YYx1SllyICUdPiZEUg2WKkwp9mWk51+D7tudSSn+buy6eNuutldbzbgZ/VknUQBXMHNs2BCWaIAx9wcBDx8ohj3cOIflIK/jR8heqd4Eh/ItHHBWd3l4U2TnA3h9Brar72A/CsWCNaKuIsCcDPhJFKtLn2PKSYk1mxpxKVbZP/WaVoTcHzfaUsxxCVxAE6Vky7ztKJI0SF1pLzv2v5Pc3Zl68Z9X8hZrbZ5nwJ4r5KApa1tLx14nDXYOZFL0/B30oSsCY4eHyyY91Mf38K/jRwSNXvMtJHZd/sJG6HsNzciA2xphZ6zcEX91mJ2s/kr+0tW8W2mkCpTFvnfBDAfPLvaLg0gr8zqVxnpczkhODSXuLnM2nWANgthqYIffm2Ufc2EjAnRdAco5i+dRHxd/UkVF1hBviypngE8XCPY90DiN5VU4zC8VSvq9l8FNFHaYq/Nspske/R0NRCrzn44qwc7Xk8jXl7OKmswbNItqP7iRO/u/zof1ES5W0DNG3QR8mhXCqmKk++LiK0wnL8DayR9QDwoAQ9rxYNywaB5reC6r4somxR+pJ9bmH/JGUC9FZydTXNNqvQW06LiImsQm8Q0T+Ygj8NWYXeV4n+VqXMYMrVjfP7NaXQay6+hkp6YV+JrBglVst6auNzCz/0f7GbkuD/YMKpBaOUifGTDB/G4Ejr8FklMTxTRJMxBcY8iRMyy5+Q0I5L0Op5igbEKFJfakJvjCXtGUT3klImT/OWhWbe5q2r0IxC3uYtC822ZFW8nHDaeVMJvSLy1V1xybwXcejDDriaCF+wTCcaTilXaxNMPlecrpxWEvXMkV1PzqnNM++yg3KkDZ8JV6S+nK2shLY7rK1JKG1VXACLjP9n3chYRP87kHjPupHBZuQC0S5tHlOwcapj1o2MK+n/443/1VtsbLkIl6McvnkNBWGXk68s6KJYYDv48TXpfLrxd6A5nWOZTjRdYttCtAfw7XS8q5gspmJcoO5GOdJniAxkTt9KY3ZFYa0SXMrBz0XqSzYZpzkcr71V4gVD1ChZI6uMv9s5nobchhzgK2PqhkPmQgheMLj+Dg5P2ybi61gAPzbeL1AWgyyocfzuVk3EVxYskTQ4Ezu4Ynil70YTd7ZDkjwkCtuUrMPlxJC88I7U2UdMg24y0FaKefsU5a2aO42lqLSUDFhKQb/muX1F68vP6f0TR3ouz8HZn1Gg914Od2uwhsyL00rRBNsYdbsgqf604O/Lky/TR9woMaFJcaGchnU33RdzSQ7HaxWVrxAPS0JAiB2C6zWhZ+J9xwbn0HuecWYmPpYnCeZu0qIyXLjDpqr5QxatLxdkpOe+Y02OT4/e30HocQA2/7YlycIIFzHXvkiq/wOHO1XMb6oXcyoUdpyVkoUvs3+rJSbQFYPp3VyU1zmOyQ1NxFdWLJGwsjB7azfheWtYgIUeO/JLjg3y6SA2yfXlwh50eop2WEE7WW07yvOM4zfzym4mVxetL1mIJoX9MFgocCwdb+QcJPcV2IBj/7S83Tqj3C4SpGqrrSbVP9SyHg11xonM3SSPm387G74a5JTqpsKMAhwnH4Wuoh32EKHluituupAa2aXEQm8FvbuuqJyQzyaVK6pkcHeW51PJgbXBcfR9zypl5tLqfIClBgkZ3OagXUG5l0XryzA4ORTGfGpJEjgGi031GfQ+xMEc5yPEXlHKzKB4wiGWQq9KfMEhFuTQl8zXcKOtw+iQiSi0oUV5tpjwIaan8JX1p/E8jQRwHmZ9U/D1jCyaMHbrbSMC9qZNthVJfvQairfa5LhreBrtnFznQKuhlnZsn3Cgfd2g2xZx2ADn2Z7vUD+HcXDsV9H6EkqO4iGWdB0l+NTcHdew0CizwnIzo5Z2hqMOE+hDvD9syTvvsN5uSWcLjiG0PaR0NNH9JgdeinCIqAZXvu6j8i4hWxymlnSny3/Adyiop48q2AnAu0Qbl6tpi5lGfZstTzfhoNGoYNQfULn5lhO1vUxOk1Y7A65ofXkO1alpvxo49CYqEJXLnWVRN0fYj40pa2aVbLEMPp1C9bM/KSuqaCzUWx5B9qpB05DCH6ihpQg9DuX52DLerh2FTpVEeUgEr1xbLW6RqpJ8TZMur90YDgJOMpkOoItstsTki+6q3KWbtFLXKvcbqOd2FbAv24kj3qz7kgSaURQzuCYmNKMLxdvVJ2R8DKJI+rUJixprv29HnY4rOJfKT0v41rQ4n9qZnjBJr0iptSahpQi91orwSvLrtaZ7cUqyUWN92g/fSB6Yh5dH7LL0VG4u2uxwDlsSOij5nzdQvBTk405TUr6StCs2U0uSkK7l7g0kszmc2PvF1F+kvoQcxcOpbpMU879aNMMtVDbJ1LiSyq+IuMxptHLqzIUJdVdLyqBJ84YSElEroRUNtOBox9DngVo5u40FH19G1VaCm81yG3I8PqylCD1IPCDPyzsjFsVByrzc4rpBVSupJdzoJnHS3iGpPDOVrIRGW5XSAaOVdlbLkefjxYTh+2JLYtbapJbdrtBukQyKCXLogZbGtS7CrDVRtL4M8FNF8G0RTegO6TdOnytRwHQUWks9TFsn3zlZuUu3JDGWNr9VL+VknAYRMhNFa2LtvSR3LpQTA0UL5gXuebFOHlH+35jjTXdoYUIPytWaJUlAeC5hXm5PO292djxvLRREcRfwZMEYMp3inkYJUIzLBzRRLRoh31Af98xz2AEtWl9CJhtrxXHPeMsUOojJ+ZxD3U85nord1/KIrlAgJh3OmRcOV9Kgop5tCZfEp0FLE3oBfqZYG3HPckmxy4RhovGwFmI+K8WJneel1Br6i/nHWoop4aco90HYYoCYtnE5vgvk6Ko0cXNF6kuIw32iooGYzytyGogrqiQNb35M3fPl5OY0t5PtIodu8kXk5jPNQhPPG7vLJK+PWZCfLpOp3RKFHiR85X7yLWvz5nKbCAmXwdZBBlBXmZAbxSfzrqiYjY4fkgWdhJduspO6RsIlZinxcWnQVmLHekoA8iZJOfswJlzDBUXqS4hJOlR2EPeWlXWJmNx55FX2kwVlX9Gql0m8ZV0O31ojfdlTeN9k8L44B97Tolb6tIfwtUHiCl/P6Xa7SkR7iWLoYczL5bKhNacZ5o2Hh4dH8WHr8/Lw8PBoEfBCz8PDo6LghZ6Hh0dFwQs9Dw+PioIXeh4eHhUFL/Q8PDwqCv8OAAD//y0geR/xjp98AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',
    'image64': 'data:image/png;base64,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',
    'isAnonym': 'true',
    'sellerName': 'Вячеслав'
}
```

заберите (из `image64`, например) данные в виде строки:

```
img_str = response['image64'].split(',')[1]
```

оставив все после запятой:

```
'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'
```

преобразуйте в `base64`:

```
import base64

img_data = base64.b64decode(img_str)
```

и сохраните:

```
with open('some_image.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_data)
```

В итоге в файле some_image.png - картинка номера Вячеслава ;)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У Вас уже есть картинка, просто она - base64 - coded. Достаточно раскодировать! Правда, я попробовал - у меня не получилось. Какие то строчки странные. Обычно то, что надо было раскодировать, было разбито на строки по 64 символа, между котрыми были переводы строк. А тут - непонятное что то.

А теперь - полная версия ответа:

Видимо, сотрудники Авито предусмотрели интерес разных роботов к опубликованным у них номерам телефонов.

К сожалению - или к счастью - защититься от человека, который решил скачать картинку, практически невозможно.

Правда, для этого нужно точно сэмулировать работу браузера.

Это включает в себя следующее:

1. понять, как работают скрипты на странице. я практически уверен, что картинка скачивается при помощи rest api, и скриптом вставляется на нужное место на странице.
2. при обращении к этому же api нужно точно сэмулировать заголовки браузера, так как их очень легко проверить на серверной стороне.

В своём проекте я, к примеру, устанавливаю заголовки вот таким образом:

```
        var restClient = new RestClient(url);
        restClient.DefaultParameters.Clear();
        restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ar;q=0.2");
        restClient.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36";
        restClient.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
```

Для того, чтобы просмотреть и "хакнуть" протокол загрузки картинок, есть раздичные инструменты. Я рекомендую [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - это, по моему, справедливо признанный лидер на этом фронте.